# Is it proper definition of the free motion? The orbit of free motion is a free group

Tags: classical-mechanics, group-theory

That's what I wrote in my notes but I don't understand this definition, I've studied group theory but free groups were not included.

Can someone explain this definition, please?

Comment: You're going to have to supply more details, although initially this looks like a math problem rather than a physics problem.

Comment: I am not sure you are talking about physics, at all, but if you are, then you may be talking about Lie groups... and there is very little left that you would have to consider on your own. The theory of Lie groups has been very deeply explored in mathematical physics.

Comment: I was looking at my old Theory of special relativity notes and when we derivated the equations of free motion (principle of least action etc.) we wrote the following: "by the way, the orbit of free motion is a free group". We didn't use this statement at all. 
I don't understand what it has to do with free motion, nor what it means at all. That's why I've asked.